# How to download GGTS 3.2.0 with grails 2.2.1

Tags: grails

i was trying so many links for downloading GGTS but i was not able to find a link, can anyone provide me a link for downloading GGTS 3.2.0 with grails 2.2.1 for windows7 32bits

Answer (score 2):

GGTS 3.2.0 Installer
http://dist.springsource.com/release/STS/3.2.0/dist/e3.8/groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.2.0.RELEASE-e3.8.2-win32-installer.exe

or zip file if you prefer:
http://dist.springsource.com/release/STS/3.2.0/dist/e3.8/groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.2.0.RELEASE-e3.8.2-win32.zip

Grails 2.2.1 (uncompress and setup path from GGTS)
http://dist.springframework.org.s3.amazonaws.com/release/GRAILS/grails-2.2.1.zip

Comment: Thanks Corso, finally i found the link http://www.springsource.org/downloads/sts-ggts

Comment: It can be found here http://dist.springsource.com/release/STS/index.html  https://dist.springsource.com/release/STS/3.6.4.RELEASE/dist/e4.5/groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.6.4.RELEASE-e4.5-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz for Linux