# 404 at GGTS download page

Tags: grails, ggts, spring-io

Looking to download GGTS (Groovy/Grails tools suite) IDE but I'm getting 404 page.
https://spring.io/tools/ggts/all/ 
https://spring.io/tools/ggts

Does someone know another place to download GGTS suite

Comment: any update on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Spring Tool Suite(STS)](https://spring.io/tools3/sts/all) also by setting Grails SDK.

Also now Netbeans also support for groovy so you can check with it also.
Intellij Idea is the best universal option for all.

BTW you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17649469/how-to-download-ggts-3-2-0-with-grails-2-2-1)  answer for downloading GGTS.

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: It can be found here http://dist.springsource.com/release/STS/index.html  https://dist.springsource.com/release/STS/3.6.4.RELEASE/dist/e4.5/groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.6.4.RELEASE-e4.5-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz for Linux as  per comment on other answer